# Centering a Display:inline; element

Tags: css, alignment, center, inline

I can´t center this element. I believe it is because of display:inline; in the CSS block. Does anyone have an idea?

```
 <p class="mr">Monatliche Rate  </p>
 <a class="info">
 <div class="circle-text"> 
 <div>?</div></div>  
 <span> Netto-Rate</span>
 </a>
 <p class="mr">: 
 <span id="results"></span> €</p>
```

CSS

```
.mr {
 color: #1d6912;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top:2px;

 text-align:center;
 **display:inline;**
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to center .mr?

Comment: What's the point of first forcing something to collapse to its content width (with display:inline) and then trying to center it within the margins you just removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your question and the 1st answer I have prepared 3 examples for you to choose from:
http://jsfiddle.net/mofeenster/6V6Z7/1/

The simplest answer is this:

```
.mr {
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: But OP wants it `inline`, which is much different than `table`. Maybe he could accept `inline-table`, but then `margin:auto` doesn't center.

Comment: If that is the case, what is the reason?

Comment: thanks this gave me the right direction, Works now like this:  

    #m1, #info-box{
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #m-wrapper{
       display: table;
    }

Answer (score 2):

You can place it in a wrapper, and add `text-align:center` to the wrapper.

```html
<div class="mr-wrapper">
    <p class="mr">Monatliche Rate</p>
</div>
```

```css
.mr-wrapper {
    text-align:center
}
.mr {
    display: inline;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6V6Z7/)